# RoR: escape_javascript and render :partial

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, partial

While updating my Rails application from ruby 1.8 to 2.1, I ran into the following problem. The code I used before in the controller:

```
  def upload_partial()
    escape_javascript(render :partial => "plupload_partial")
  end
```

doesn't seem to be working anymore.

routes.rb:

```
match 'items/upload_partial' => 'items#upload_partial', :via => [:get, :post]
```

The view contains some HTML along with JavaScript. I'm getting following error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `gsub' for #<Array:0x00000003f35590>):
  app/controllers/item_controller.rb:31:in `upload_partial'
```

When I remove the escape_javascript(), the code executes correctly. I guess this function expects a string and uses the gsub() function to escape the JS, but render :partial doesn't return a proper string (anymore) as of Ruby 2.x

Anyone had a similar problem?

Comment: Please show some context.

Comment: You render partial in your controller? Why?

Comment: The application has an upload button, and when a user clicks on it, the application does a request to the rails app (via routes.rb), the controller picks this up, and returns the correct view. This view contains HTML with JavaScript. The code worked perfectly before I updated Ruby and when I remove the escape_javascript() function. I think something changed in what the render :partial returns or what escape_javascript() expects, or maybe there is just a better way of doing this.